# Is it possible to import a Laravel web project to Flutter

Tags: android, laravel, flutter, store, playback

I want to know if I can create an entire web project on the Laravel platform, and after completing it, I can run an update and edit the project on the Flutter platform.

I want to make my website into a Play Store app. So that people can get my website on their smartphone from the Play Store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding something:

You **cannot** directly run or edit a Laravel web project in Flutter. Instead, you use Flutter to create a mobile app that **connects** to your Laravel backend through API calls.

So, Laravel will handle all the server-side logic/API endpoints. Meanwhile, Flutter will be used to build the mobile user interface and manage user interactions on the front end.

Comment: thanks for for good suggestion and i have a question to clear my doubt that does flutter only for front end or frontend backend both.

Comment: @MahidulHasan Flutter a UI framework - so it's only for the frontend.